# Ошибка при копировании из 1 файла в другой. Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, копирование

Выдает ошибку при копирование 1 тексового файла во 2.

Что делать?

```py
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print (f"Копирования данных из файла {from_file} в файл {to_file}" )

##открытие файла

in_file = open(from_file,encoding='utf-8' )
indata = in_file.read()

##копирования файла

print(f" Исходный файл имеет размер {len(indata)} байл.")

print(f"Целевой файл существует?{exists(to_file)}")
print("Готов, нажми Enter для продолжения или CTRL+C для отмены.")
input()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.white(indata)

print("Отлично, все сделано.")

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

При вводе.

```
C:\Python\pabota5>pabota5.py te1.txt te2.txt
Копирования данных из файла te1.txt в файл te2.txt
 Исходный файл имеет размер 29 байл.
Целевой файл существует?True
Готов, нажми Enter для продолжения или CTRL+C для отмены.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\pabota5\pabota5.py", line 22, in <module>
    out_file.white(indata)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'white'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в вашем коде опечатка в строке 22, о чем и говорит ошибка.
Правильная строка:

```
out_file.write(indata)
```